# Arista: Unexpected results when pinging MLAG SVI

Tags: arista

My understanding of Arista's implementation of MC-LAG is relatively weak, so its likely I've misunderstood a deliberate limitation of how the `mlag` works.

Taking a basic example,

[image: Mlag]

Where,

```
switch1: 
  vlan10-svi: 192.168.0.1/24
switch2: 
  vlan10-svi: 192.168.0.2/24
switch3: 
  vlan10-svi: 192.168.0.3/24
```

So in a given scenario of switch3 pinging each of the SVI's on switch1 and switch2, I'd expect to see,

```
# ping 192.168.0.1
80 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.338 ms
# ping 192.168.0.2
80 bytes from 192.168.0.2: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.338 ms
```

Whereas in reality,

```
# ping 192.168.0.1
80 bytes from 192.168.0.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.338 ms
# ping 192.168.0.2
1 packets transmitted, 0 received, 100% packet loss, time 0ms
```

It is also the same when attempting to ping each respective SVI from switch1 <=> switch2.

If the either port on the portchannel on switch3 is shutdown - then reachability of each respective switch is possible - but it is never possible to ping both switch1 and switch2.

---

Now, I understand that [VARP](https://eos.arista.com/active-active-router-redundancy-using-varp/) is likely the tool used to allow reachability of both devices (and in fact, does); but in the example where each switch needs to be independently accessed (eg. for management outside of `ma1`) - it doesn't appear to be possible.

- Is this simply L3 limitation/design of Arista's MLAG?
- Should it be possible to ping between the mlag peers (not using the mlag peer link)
- Should it be possible for switch3 to be able to ping both switch1 and switch2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would appear this is a simple one.

I believed that the peer link should only contain the `mlag` communication VLAN (rather than everything), so on the peer link port channel simply replacing,

```
switchport trunk allowed vlan 4094
```

With

```
switchport trunk allowed vlan 10,4094
```

Immediately provided ICMP response from both sw3 to sw1,sw2 and between sw1 and sw3.

`show spanning tree` confirms there are no blocked interfaces, so Arista is clearing working some voodoo to prevent L2 loops with the mlag peer link.